# Код не срабатывает на планшете

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Есть блок, который появ./скрыв. по клику.

Вот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    $('#demo-text').hide();
    $('#demo-link').click(function (e) {
      var $message = $('#demo-text');

      if ($message.css('display') != 'block') {
        $message.show();

        var yourClick = true;
        $(document).bind('click.myEvent', function (e) {
          if (!yourClick && $(e.target).closest('#demo-text').length == 0) {
            $message.hide();
            $(document).unbind('click.myEvent');
          }
          yourClick = false;
        });
      } 
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

На мобиле касание на область вне блока закрывает блок, а на планшете - нет! Как сделать, чтобы и на планшете заработало?

Comment: для начала - проверить на нескольких браузерах

Comment: проверен в разных, везде не пашет

Comment: @cevil, почистите кэш в браузере планшета, если не поможет, то желательно попробовать воссоздать проблему на [сайте jsfiddle][1], потому что проблема может быть в css, которого здесь нет.

1: http://jsfiddle.net/